# CSF/LFD configuration settings

Tags: linux, csf

```
/bin/gtar -c -f - -X /home/{USER}/cpbackup-exclude.conf -X /etc/cpbackup-exclude.conf .
```

How can I white list these strings?

I've tried stuff like:

```
pcmd: /bin/gtar -c -f - -X /home/*
```

and still reports them. I don't want to whitelist the execu since i want to know when its used for something else.